# Am I missing something or Unity3d skips frames?

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision-detection, coroutine, frame-rate

I have a gun with 4 muzzles. Each muzzle can fire a bullet (so 4 bullets can be fired at once). In my scene I have 100 guns thus 400 bullets can be fired at the same time.

The problem is, if the number of gun is below 20 then it is Ok, but if I raise it to above 20, some of the bullets go through the target (a big Cube). And ton of bullets pass through the Cube if it is above 100.

This is the code that check for collision:

```
private IEnumerator ProjectileCoroutine() {

    while (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, Target.transform.position) > 5)
    {                            
        yield return null;
    }

    Explode();
    yield break;
}
```

Some notes:

- Games runs at 49 - 68 fps (100 guns on the scene)
- I uses prefab pooling method
- Above code is run in a separated coroutine (StartCoroutine)

Please can anyone tell me what is happening?
I suspect that Unity skips some of the frames as Coroutine has some connections to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think Unity is "skipping frames". That said, I expect your coroutine will only run once per full graphics frame. Physics updates usually occur more often, especially at lower frame rates.

Note that the more bullets there are, the slower the scene probably runs. For a time-stepped physics simulation, this means that bullets have to move further every time step. If the bullets are moving fast, and the time step is large, it is possible for bullets to move too far through the cube for collisions to be detected and resolved in a frame. If this is the problem, you may need to add some sort of ray casting, to better detect collisions.

That said, I don't think your ProjectileCoroutine is the best way of resolving collisions. For starters, it appears to check a sphere, rather than a cube, and running it for every bullet is a bad idea performance wise.

It would be much better to use an appropriate Collider, and rely on the actual physics engine to detect collisions, instead of doing a manual distance check.

Comment: Thank bro! - you saved my day :)

It turns out to be time-stepped problem as you mentioned. So I go to [Edit] -> [Project Settings] -> [Time] and reduce [Maximum Allowed Timestep] to 0.02 and then hit Play again. No impact on performace (actually its +10fps faster) and ALL bullets stop passing through the cube.

Also, I switched back to Raycasting method to check for collision. Initially i suspect that Raycasting have huge impact on performance so i tried a pure Math solution.

One more point, moving collider(s) heavily impact performance especially when you have many. :)